# Solving the complex equation $\sin(\sin(z)) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've seen multiple examples of how to solve for $\sin(z) = 0$, however how may I go about solving $\sin(\sin(z))=0$?

My thoughts are to start with rewriting $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$
And then trying to find when $\sin(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i})=0$

Since sin doesn't have a well-defined inverse I'm not sure as to which method I should use to solve this. All tips appreciated

Comment: $\sin z=k\pi$ and then it's a quadratic in $e^{iz}$ for each integer $k$ etc

Comment: If it's a quadratic in $e^{iz}$ for each integer $k$, what does that tell me with regards to the solutions being equal to zero? I'm slightly shaky on these relations

Comment: You solve the quadratic and get $e^{iz}$ and then for each solution, you get the infinitely many $z$ there; overall you have solutions parametrized by two integers (and a plus minus when $k \ne 0$)

Comment: The solutions are given by $$\left(c_1|c_2\right)\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(z=2 \pi 
   c_2-\sin ^{-1}\left(2 \pi  c_1\right)+\pi \lor z=2
   \pi  c_2+\sin ^{-1}\left(2 \pi  c_1\right)\lor z=2
   \pi  c_2-\sin ^{-1}\left(2 \pi  c_1+\pi \right)+\pi
   \lor z=2 \pi  c_2+\sin ^{-1}\left(2 \pi  c_1+\pi
   \right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition

$$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

so that

$$\sin z=0\iff e^{2iz}=1\iff z=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

thus we need to solve

$$\sin z=k\pi\implies\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

let $x=e^{iz}$ so that

$$x-x^{-1}=2ik\pi \implies x^2-2ik\pi x-1=0\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

which by the quadratic formula forms

$$x=ik\pi \pm\sqrt{1-k^2\pi^2} \implies e^{iz}=ik\pi \pm\sqrt{1-k^2\pi^2}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

from which we can take logarithms of both sides to solve for $z$.